# Ethernet extender kit claims to send data through power cables - Is this correct?

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication

[image: BT ethernet extenders]

I own an ethernet extender kit which has two devices connected to mains. Its [data sheet](https://www.bt.com/content/dam/bt/help/legacy-ug/broadband-and-wi-fi-devices/Broadband%20Extender%20600%20Kit%20spec%20sheet.pdf) claims that the device *"your homes electrical wiring to extend your broadband network anywhere in the house"*. An informative [youtube video](https://youtu.be/mVU3_ffn48o?t=20) also suggests that the data is transferred from your mains.

The little I know about 3 pin power sockets makes me think that this is impossible. I strongly suspect that both devices have receivers and transmitters within them that transmit the data. Is there any way I can prove/disprove this?

Comment: What exactly do you think that's impossible? What is it that you want to disprove?

Comment: Data transmission over mains has been a thing for > 40 years.

Comment: Look up Power-line communication on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication

Comment: Power line communication is proof that data can be transmitted through mains. Thanks

Comment: @NMech I thought it was impossible to transmit data over mains; Three pin sockets have AC which seems difficult to transmit data through

Comment: Power-line communications systems operate by adding a modulated carrier signal to the wiring system. Different types of power-line communications use different frequency bands.   Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing (OFDM) is the basic transmission technique .  The basic idea of OFDM is to divide the available spectrum into several narrowband, low data rate subcarriers. I'm on a mobile now but maybe later I'll write a proper explanation.

Comment: On a side note, it is my understanding that those device will only work within your house where the sockets you plug them into are on the same pole in you fuse panel.

Comment: Phase couplers or having a device that uses all phases (e.g. oven) can help with that

Comment: The RF can really annoy nearby radio amateurs, making some bands unuseable.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can prove/disprove this?

Yes. Run an extension lead from your neighbour's house to power one of the devices. It should fail due to either distance or your neighbour being on a different phase of the mains.